# Выравнивание размера изображений в карусели по вертикали

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap4

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="src/img/navLogo.png">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                       data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Наши контакты
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Как с нами связаться?</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Где нас найти?</a>

                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://cdn.bitrix24.ru/b205787/landing/4fa/4fa630f6ec6e609b82b65ce6e7585c28/nasza_flota.jpg" alt="First slide">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://cdn.bitrix24.ru/b205787/landing/a40/a40b2b078db49f9c2e23233d228b87c3/2_2x.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://cdn.bitrix24.ru/b205787/landing/788/788484872f6143c0511ec4faefbeabb7/5_2x.jpg" alt="Third slide">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Доброго времени суток. Хотел бы узнать. В данном случае можно ли как то изменить размер слайдов к какой то общей величине? Или здесь проблема в самих исходных изображениях?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не особо понятно, что именно вы хотите сделать, но, скорее всего, можно.

Можете попробовать поиграться со свойством `object-fit` для изображений, отображение которых вы хотите изменить.

```css
.carousel-item {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="src/img/navLogo.png">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                       data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Наши контакты
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Как с нами связаться?</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Где нас найти?</a>

                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="d-block w-100 h-100" src="https://cdn.bitrix24.ru/b205787/landing/4fa/4fa630f6ec6e609b82b65ce6e7585c28/nasza_flota.jpg" alt="First slide">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100 h-100" src="https://cdn.bitrix24.ru/b205787/landing/a40/a40b2b078db49f9c2e23233d228b87c3/2_2x.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100 h-100" src="https://cdn.bitrix24.ru/b205787/landing/788/788484872f6143c0511ec4faefbeabb7/5_2x.jpg" alt="Third slide">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```